# Dataset, For Loop to return row value for match

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, dataset

I have a dataset "ds" which is mapped to a table with "Index", "FirstName", "LastName" as columns.
I have a Text Box field, txtfname.
I want to know the row which matches this txtfname in the dataset so that I can make updates...
But my code does not even go into the "if" loop.... so I cannot grab the row...

Can you guys tell me what I may be doing wrong?

```
      for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {

            if (txtfname.Text == ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["first_name"])
            {
                int inc = i;
            }

        }
```

Thank you..

Comment: Try casting the right side to string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't wanna compare a string to an object, cast the right side to string.

```
if (txtfname.Text == (string) ds.Tables[0].Rows[i]["first_name"])
```